# Copying folders using shutil and dictionary

Tags: python

My goal is to copy folders to a different location,The structure of the directory is such that i have multiple folders which have subfolders of thier own,I dont want all the subfolders to be copied,i just want a particular three of them.

I have created a dictionary where the the key is the name of the main folder and the value is again a dictinary of three folders i want where the key is the kind of folder i want and the value are the folder name in the original directory i want copied.

It looks like this:

```
't0107': {'Arteirial': 'ARTERIAL THIN',
'Portal': '5mm portal',
'Venous': 'VENOUS THIN'},
't011': {'Arteirial': 'ARTERIAL THIN_0131',
'Portal': '5mm portal',
'Venous': 'VENOUS THIN'},
't0112': {'Arteirial': 'Thin Arterial Phase',
'Portal': 'Thin Portal Phase',
'Venous': 'Thin Venous Phase'},
't0113': {'Arteirial': 'Thin Arterial Phase',
'Portal': 'Thin Portal Phase',
'Venous': 'Thin Venous Phase'},
```

Im trying to use shutil.copytree to get this done where im trying

```
def copytree(src, dst, symlinks=False,ignore = None):
    for item in os.listdir(src):
        s = os.path.join(src, item)
        d = os.path.join(dst, item)
        if os.path.isdir(s):
            shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore)
        else:
            shutil.copy2(s, d)
path = '/media/username/ce162bb5-5654-4c36-9db2-55c7728ddb5a/CT/Anup/PhaseWise/'

for item in data_dict.keys():
   copytree(str(path)+str(item)+'/'+data_dict[item]['Arteirial']+'/','/media/username/da5df9e4-cdc6-4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/lion/'+str(item))
```

Nothings working,any suggestions are welcome,Thanks in advance

EDIT:
The code works but there is a problem,

When the directories are copied beacause i run the command `os.mkdir(dist_path+level1+level2)` in the loop it goes to the destination 
and makes a directory t004ARTERIAL THIN t004VENOUS THIN is there any way at all that the program could first make the t004 directory 
and then make the ARTERIAL THIN.VENOUS THIN etc folders inside it and then transfer?

```
root_path = "/media/username/ce162bb5-5654-4c36-9db2-55c7728ddb5a/LiverCT/Anup/PhaseWise/"
dist_path = "/media/username/da5df9e4-cdc6-4d55-91e8-b2383e89165f/lion/"

for level1,value1 in data_dict.items():
    for level2, value2 in value1.items():
        src_path = os.path.join(root_path,str(level1),str(value2))
        os.mkdir(dist_path+level1+level2)
    #print (src_path)
        copytree(src_path,dist_path+level1+level2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. use os.path.join() to replace string concatenation.
2. shutil.copytree will copy all folders and files from your source folder to dist folder. Not necessary to pack it again.

Demo Code:

```
d = {'t0107': {'Arteirial': 'ARTERIAL THIN',
'Portal': '5mm portal',
'Venous': 'VENOUS THIN'},
't011': {'Arteirial': 'ARTERIAL THIN_0131',
'Portal': '5mm portal',
'Venous': 'VENOUS THIN'},
't0112': {'Arteirial': 'Thin Arterial Phase',
'Portal': 'Thin Portal Phase',
'Venous': 'Thin Venous Phase'},
't0113': {'Arteirial': 'Thin Arterial Phase',
'Portal': 'Thin Portal Phase',
'Venous': 'Thin Venous Phase'}}

src_path = "/home/username/src"
dst_path = "home/username/dst"
for level1,value1 in d.iteritems():
    for level2, value2 in value1.iteritems():
        from_path = os.path.join(src_path,level1,level2,value2)
        to_path = os.path.join(dst_path,level1,level2,value2)
        print from_path
        # os.mkdir(to_path)
        shutil.copytree(from_path,to_path) # the to_path will be created automatically, if the to_path is exists, it will raise OSError: [Errno 17] File exists.
```

Output Lines:

```
/home/username/src/t011/Arteirial/ARTERIAL THIN_0131
/home/username/src/t011/Venous/VENOUS THIN
/home/username/src/t011/Portal/5mm portal
/home/username/src/t0113/Arteirial/Thin Arterial Phase
/home/username/src/t0113/Venous/Thin Venous Phase
/home/username/src/t0113/Portal/Thin Portal Phase
/home/username/src/t0112/Arteirial/Thin Arterial Phase
/home/username/src/t0112/Venous/Thin Venous Phase
/home/username/src/t0112/Portal/Thin Portal Phase
/home/username/src/t0107/Arteirial/ARTERIAL THIN
/home/username/src/t0107/Venous/VENOUS THIN
/home/username/src/t0107/Portal/5mm portal
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply let me try this,

Comment: I have updated my demo code, and I am a little confused, If I got wrong, please show me what the target directory structure.@Ryan

Comment: Sorry, internet is causing pain here,let me check and let you know

Comment: Can we please take this to chat?@guichao

Comment: I cant thank you enough,was stuck on this for 2days,Thanks a million

Comment: Q:Can we please take this to chat? A: How?@Ryan